# Error: image orgsync/java8 not found

Tags: docker

I'm new to Docker and just cloned this repo:

https://hub.docker.com/r/clifton/ib-gateway/

I then ran the build on dockerhub, and got this error:

```
Starting to clone
Cloning into '.'...
Cloning done
Starting Build
KernelVersion: 3.13.0-40-generic
Os: linux
BuildTime: 2016-02-22T21:37:01.910365059+00:00
ApiVersion: 1.22
Version: 1.10.2
GitCommit: c3959b1
Arch: amd64
GoVersion: go1.5.3
Starting build of index.docker.io/vgoklani/docker-ib-gateway:latest...
Step 1 : FROM orgsync/java8
Error: image orgsync/java8 not found
```

https://hub.docker.com/r/vgoklani/docker-ib-gateway/builds/bbaiqpyxasq6lg3sd6nzgp5/

Any ideas on what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear, the orgsync/java8 image does not exist. It may have been deleted. Causing build fail.
You can replace it by the official java image by replacing orgsync/java8 by java in the dockerfile